# Tcl_CreateCommand invalid type conversion

Tags: c++, tcl

I am creating a new TCL command using tcl.h with the following code:

```
#include <tcl.h>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


int saludo (ClientData clientData,Tcl_Interp *interp, int argc,char *argv[])

            {cout << "Hello World";}



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


    Tcl_Interp *interp;

    interp = Tcl_CreateInterp();


    Tcl_CreateCommand(interp, "sal", saludo, ClientData(NULL), (Tcl_CmdDeleteProc *)NULL);


}
```

But I get the error>

```
[arch@myLinux tcl_interpreter]$ make
g++    -c -o interpreter.o interpreter.cc
interpreter.cc: In Funktion »int main(int, char**)«:
interpreter.cc:24:87: Fehler: ungültige Umwandlung von »const char     (*)(ClientData, Tcl_Interp*, int, char**) {aka const char (*)(void*,     Tcl_Interp*, int, char**)}« in »int (*)(ClientData, Tcl_Interp*, int, const     char**) {aka int (*)(void*, Tcl_Interp*, int, const char**)}« [-fpermissive]
   Tcl_CreateCommand(interp, "sal", saludo, ClientData(NULL),     (Tcl_CmdDeleteProc *)NULL);
```

I alreadz know it is c code and I am using -fpermissive in the command line>

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -fpermissive
```

but it doesnt seem to work. I am using gcc 5.2.

Any ideas thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the declaration:

```c
int saludo (ClientData clientData,Tcl_Interp *interp, int argc,char *argv[])
```

That's not the `const`-correct version. You need to use:

```c
int saludo (ClientData clientData,Tcl_Interp *interp, int argc,const char *argv[])
```

This is because the strings that will be passed into your code *must not* be modified by your function (because they are observed by other parts of the code which assume that they will not be modified). Note that really old versions of Tcl might not require you to be `const` correct, but that was a fault of the description of the API (many years ago); the strings were never allowed to be modified since the release of 8.0 onwards.